# Pass a parameter to the backend

Tags: java, html

I'm on a page and I want to pass the parameter when I click a download link.

report?name=something

The problem is that I can't get the request.getParameter("name") because it's already another link

How do I do this then? I need to pass the name

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getFile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getSpool(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String environmentName = request.getParameter("name");
    String url = Report.getFileFromContainer(environmentName);
    try {
        InputStream in = new URL(url).openStream();
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file-" + environmentName + ".zip");
        IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
        in.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

HTML

```
 <a href="/getFile"></a>
```

Comment: <a href="/getFile"></a> ... where do you see parameters in that? is this a rest service? do you know how to call a rest service?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the parameter. Then only you can get it. Here is the answer:

```
**<a href="/getFile?name=INDIA"></a>**
```